# Hide part of image outside boundary in SVG Image

Tags: html, css, image, d3.js, svg

I have appended an image to SVG. 
My requirement is I want to hide part of image going outside boundary.
So if some part of my image is going beyond 1 or 500 , it should get hidden.

I think this can be done using CSS or using viewBox attribute of SVG but I don't know how to do this.

This is link for my http://jsfiddle.net/zeajrgdr/72/.
and this is how I append image

```
 var pathPlot = d3.selectAll("g." + "fp-pathplot-1419951398667");
      var image = d3.selectAll('#floor-image');
      if (image != null) {
        image.remove();
        removeAllImageSelectors();
      }
      var img = pathPlot.append("svg:image")
        .attr('x', 100)
        .attr('y', 100)
        .attr('width', 196)
        .attr('height', 98)
        .attr('id', 'floor-image')
        .attr('preserveAspectRatio', 'defer')
        .attr("xlink:href", "http://s12.postimg.org/wm0u4pgf1/Rotate_Img_AS2.png")
```

Click on 'Add Image' button to add image. You can drag,rotate this image by mouse.
Thanks.

Comment: just add a clip path when you append the image : http://bl.ocks.org/couchand/6399221

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like @thisOneGuy said, you need a clip path. Add its declaration right after svg tag:

```
        <defs>
            <clipPath id="my-clip" transform="translate(100,100)">
                <rect width="363" height="360" x="0" y="0"  ></rect> 
            </clipPath>
        </defs>
```

And then apply to all the elements you need clipped (or their container):

```
<g class="map-layers" width="363" height="360" x="0" y="0"
   clip-path="url(#my-clip)">
```

See the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hr7s1rb7/)